# Error for publishing the app in Rstudio

Tags: shiny

I want to make a plot in Rstudio and share it with others. I have already made an account in shiny website but when I want to publish the plot I have an error 
`could not find file to deploy`. Any suggestions?

```
 library(shiny)
 library(plotly)
 ui <- fluidPage(
     plotlyOutput("p")
 )
server <- function(input, output, ...) {

     output$p <- renderPlotly({
         p <- plotly_build(qplot(1:10))
         p$elementId <- NULL
         p
     })

 }
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2a1a.png)

Comment: I've tried your code and it works fine on my machine. Sorry to say something obvious but have you tried reconnecting RStudio to shinyapps.io, and updating your packages, in particular rsconnect (I'm on 0.85).

Comment: @ Chris Beeley, thanks for the comment. Please click on "enter image description here" to see the new error. Although I have already installed the MASS package but when I click on publish, I will have this error. The function works and I can get the results but I cannot publish it.

Comment: There should be files in the left hand box. I'm not at a machine at the moment, I'll do you a screenshot a bit later. You need to do something with your working directory or save it somewhere else or something to make RStudio find the files

Answer (score 2):

You should have a screen like this

[image]

I guess there's something wrong with your working directory or something like that. You could always do it by hand as detailed here, with rsconnect https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/shinyapps.html

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, if the file path contains special characters (even scandinavian letters) this error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when I have the app on a file server, I get the same error. When I move the folder to e.g. my desktop, then works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error and solved it as follows.
Create a folder on disk C with a simple name like shiny and create your shiny app inside it, this error occurs due to the names of folders and subfolders until you get to the folder where you are creating shiny.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested early, this issue is related to the path (maybe some special characters or its length).  Moving the working directory of the project to the root directory of your drive should solve it.